# Is there a Python type signature which matches lists, dicts and sets but not strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say that you have an arbitrary JSON object read into Python as built in Python data structures. Say that you want to recursively traverse this structure and perform some operation on all primitive values, and recurse deeper on collections.

```
def recursiveMap(something, func):
  if isinstance(something, Collection):
    for item in something:
      return recursiveMap(item, func)
  else:
    return func(something)
```

So my question is: Is there a type Collection which would match lists and dictionaries but not strings?

Sourcing my types from https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes I've yet to find one:

```
>>> isinstance("", c.Container)
True
>>> isinstance("", c.Hashable)
True
>>> isinstance("", c.Iterable)
True
>>> isinstance("", c.Sized)
True
>>> isinstance("", c.Callable)
False
>>> isinstance({}, c.Callable)
False
>>> isinstance("", c.Sequence)
True
```

This is not a question about whether or not it is correct that Python considers a string to be any of the above listed types, but rather a practical question on whether there exists some other type which fulfills the needs of the example algorithm in the first code listing.

Comment: Even if you find one, `isinstance(obj, (dict, list))` seems *significantly* clearer (using a tuple as the classinfo arg).

Comment: This may be a silly question, but why do you want `recursiveMap` to look only at dictionary keys and ignore their values? I'd expect dictionaries and lists to need different handling here.

Comment: I really don't. In the real implementation of `recursiveMap` I'll have to distinguish between sequences and associative data structures since the Python interface for iterating over the two are different. Though solving how to do that sort of depends on which abstract classes are available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One each way to handle this is simply to group together all of the types you want to match. `isinstance` will take a tuple of types as well as a single type:

```
>>> CollectionTypes = list, dict, set
>>> isinstance("", CollectionTypes)
False
>>> isinstance({}, CollectionTypes)
True
>>>
```

If you do find a predefined type that matches exactly those three types and doesn't match `str` then you've locked yourself in and when later on you decide you also need `tuple` or some other types to be included in the match you are back to square one. That's why it is better here to be explicit about the types you are matching.

Comment: This approach has the limitation that if someone at some point decides to throw an OrderedDict at the algorithm it will stop working.

Comment: That depends on the desired behaviour. `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, so it is already included in `CollectionTypes` which I would have guess is most likely what is wanted.

Comment: @Rovanion You can use `type()` if you want the other behaviour, e.g. `type(collections.OrderedDict()) in {list, dict, set}` >>> `False`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with hashable (string) vs non-hashable (list, dict, set) objects, you can use `collections.Hashable`:

```
>>> import collections
>>> isinstance([], collections.Hashable)
False
>>> isinstance({}, collections.Hashable)
False
>>> isinstance(set(), collections.Hashable)
False
>>> isinstance('', collections.Hashable)
True
```

Of course add `not` to invert the booleans.

The alternative is simply to feed multiple arguments:

```
>>> isinstance('', (set, dict, list))
False
>>> isinstance([], (set, dict, list))
True
```

Comment: `collections.Hashable` is going to go badly wrong if the OP wants to include `tuple` as one of their acceptable types. Far better just to list the exact types they'll accept.

Comment: @Duncan Well yes if they change their criteria the solution will change naturally, but agree feeding multiple arguments is probably clearer